# Testing JSF Managed Bean with Arquillian

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsf, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian

i am trying to test my `JSf` aplication with `Arquillian`. The problem i am facing is that i am unable to inject the `Managed Bean` named `TicketBean` in to my test class which is `TicketBeanTest`. What i have tried so far to inject the `TicketBean` in to `TicketBeanTest` was,

1. tried using `@ManagedProperty` but did not work , threw `NullPointerException` when i called any method on `TicketBean`
2. tried using `@inject` but thew `java.lang.RuntimeException` , stating `could not inject member`
3. tried using

   `@Before
   public void instantiate(){
   ticketBean=new TicketBean();
   }`

   but it failed to call `@PostConstruct` method inside `TicketBean` , so again `NullPointerException` while calling `DAO` method from inside `TicketBean`. 
   i am testing my application in `JBoss AS` container.

following is my Test Class,

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TicketBeanTest {
    @Inject
    TicketBean ticketBean;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(TicketBean.class, Ticket.class, TicketDao.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Before
    public void instantiate() {
        ticketBean = new TicketBean();
    }

    @Test
    public void dotest() {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.setSummary("JUnite-Arquillian Test");
        ticket.setDescription("Testing from Arquillian");
        ticket.setPriority(2);
        ticket.setStatus(2);
        ticket.setAssignedTo("alok.dac");
        ticket.setProject(100);
        ticket.setTicketId(2);
        Assert.assertEquals("home", ticketBean.updateTicket(ticket));

    }

    @Ignore
    @Test
    public void should_Return_true() {
        Assert.assertTrue(ticketBean.testArquillian());

    }
}
```

following is the `TicketBean` class ,

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ticketBean")
public class TicketBean implements Serializable {

private transient TicketDao tDao;
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
this.tDao = new TicketDao();
}
public String updateTicket(Ticket ticket) {
        boolean flag = this.tDao.updateTicket(ticket);
        if (flag) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    "",
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            "Ticket Updated Successfully !", ""));
            return "home";
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                "",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "Ticket Updated Failed ! ",
                        "Some error occured , Try Again !"));
        return Constants.ERRPAGE;
    }
}
```